# ¿Cuál es la razón por las inconsistencias desinenciales en Don Quijote?

Tags: conjugación, literatura, español-medio

Hace un par de días, emprendí la lectura de *El ingenioso hidalgo Don Quijote de la Mancha*, y ya he topado con varias inconsistencias gráfico-gramaticales que me han despertado la curiosidad.

Cónstame que al caballero Don Quijote le gusta emplear un lenguaje que ya en aquella época parecía anticuado. Empero son las inconsistencias de su hablar que me interesan, como la siguiente de la desinencia verbal de la segunda persona plural:

> Pero de vosotros, soez y baja canalla, no hago caso alguno: tirad, llegad, venid y ofendedme en cuanto pud**iéredes**, que vosotros ver**éis** el pago que llev**áis** de vuestra sandez y demasía.

Tengo algunas teorías, pero si hubiere alguien que sepa la respuesta verdadera, agradecérselo he.

Comment: En parte, pues, sería que Don Quijote fingía hablar a lo viejo pero no siéndolo, podría equivocarse.  Cervantes sí mismo se equivocó en varias cosas (el nombre de la mujer de Sancho Panza, por ejemplo).  Me parece la razón más fácil: bien Cervantes quería que Quijote se confundiese las formas, bien Cervantes sí mismo las confundía.  En el momento de escribir, las formas con la *d* intercolada ya se habrían perdido bien.  No obstante, en Portugal, la *d* pervive en la misma paradigma (*quando **puderdes**, que vós **vereis** o pago que **levais***), pero creo que ya se había perdido en s. XVII

Comment: Puede ser en efecto que, o fue intencional por parte de Cervantes que Quijote pareciese filatero malogrado, o simplemente se le saliesen las formas de hogaño por ser cómo hablaba naturalmente aunque intentara arcaizar el habla de Quijote. Antes de esta excerpta que cité, hay otro ejemplo que me resaltó, el que dejo a continuación: "¡Oh princesa Dulcinea, señora deste cautivo corazón!, mucho agravio me **habedes** fecho en despedirme y reprocharme con el riguroso afincamiento de mandarme no parecer ante la vuestra fermosura."